# Como llamar this.form.action con javascript fuera del formulario

Tags: javascript, formularios, actionscript

Este formulario se encuentra dentro de una tabla, cada fila se carga con un while, los datos los trae desde una base de datos, todo funciona correctamente:

[image: Tabla que carga formularios, con datos de la base de datos]

pero ahora quiero hacer una validación con javascript sobre si desea modificar/eliminar un formulario, pero no sé como puedo referenciar este formulario, y luego de eso, como puedo hacer el llamado a this.form.action estando afuera de este formulario

```html
<form method='POST'>

//aqui tengo inputs que contienen datos de la base de datos


/*Los inputs 'results, 'update' y 'delete', funcionan bien a través de "onclick="this.form.action=" 
pero al hacerlo así no hago validaciones en 'update' y 'delete', ahora quiero poder hacerlo y no 
logro como poder realizarlo*/
<input class='results' type='submit' onclick="this.form.action='survey-results.php'" value='Resultados' />

<input class='update' type='submit' onclick="update();" value='Modificar' />

<input class='delete' type='submit' onclick="this.form.action='survey-back-delete.php'" value='Eliminar' />

</form>


<script>

function update() {

  if (window.confirm("¿Seguro que quieres modificar esta encuesta? ")) { 
  
//aquí quiero poner el script que hace lo mismo que: this.form.action                                                    
      }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Evita usar funciones *in line*, como todos los `onclick` que estás poniendo. Dificultan el mantenimiento y la comprensión/resolución de ciertos problemas. Si por algún motivo quisieras referirte al formulario fuera de él, lo cual ni siquiera es necesario para resolver este problema, puedes darle un `id` y listo. Una forma más limpia de resolver esto sería dando una clase a cada tipo de botón, escuchar todos los clicks de los botones del form mediante eventos (no *in line*) y determinar por la clase el tipo de botón que fue pulsado para actuar en consecuencia.

Answer (score 1):

Facil, solo agrega `return` al atributo `onclick` asi:

`<input class='update' type='submit' onclick="return update();" value='Modificar' />`

agregale la pagina que va a procesar la forma asi:

`<form method='post' action="procesa_forma.php">`

y pon un if en la funcion javascript asi:

```
function update() {
   if (window.confirm("¿Seguro que quieres modificar esta encuesta?")) {
      return true;
   }
   else{
      return false;
   }
}
```

Explicacion: Si el usuario presiona `OK` el formulario se postea. Si presiona `Cancel` el formulario no se postea. Listo.

Ejemplo:

```js
function update() {
   if (window.confirm("Do you really want to leave?")) {
      this.form.action = 'modificar.php';
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
}
```

```html
<form method='post' action="procesa_forma.php">
   <input class='update' type='submit' onclick="return update();" value='Modificar' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para evitar usar eventos en línea (`onclick="... código ..."`), que va a resultar en repetición por cada botón, es mejor crear funciones específicas y agregar "escuchadores" de evento para cada botón.

Con `document.querySelectorAll()` obtienes todos los elementos que cumplan con la condición especificada, en este caso, será por la clase de los botones *.results*, *.update* y *.delete*.

Se recorren todos los botones y se asigna la función que se va a ejecutar cuando se haga clic en ellos. Cada función recibirá como parámetro el *evento* que "se lanzó", donde puedes obtener el elemento en que se hizo clic con `event.target` y, desde ahí, llegar hasta el formulario al que pertenece.

Revisa los comentarios en el código para saber cómo funciona el resto de instrucciones.

```js
// Obtener todos los botones por clase
let resBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.results');
let updBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.update');
let delBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.delete');

// Recorrer todos los botones para asignar evento onclick
resBtn.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', results));
updBtn.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', update));
delBtn.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', borrar));


// Para actualizar
function update(e) {
  if (confirm("¿Seguro que quieres modificar esta encuesta? ")) {
     // Obtener formulario, closest buscará el elemento especificado
     // en la estructura superior
     let form = e.target.closest('form');
     // Asignar acción
     form.action = 'survey-update.php';
  } else {
     // Respuesta negativa, se cancela el proceso de formulario
     e.preventDefault();
  }
}

// Para borrar
function borrar(e) {
  if (confirm("¿Seguro que quieres eliminar esta encuesta? ")) {
     let form = e.target.closest('form');
     form.action = 'survey-back-delete.php';
  } else {
     // Respuesta negativa, se cancela el proceso de formulario
     e.preventDefault();
  }
}

// Para resultados
function results(e) {
   let form = e.target.closest('form');
   form.action = 'survey-results.php';
}

/* ********** Borra desde aquí... ********** */
// Solo para probar que se aplicaron los cambios
// Obtener todos los formularios y agregar evento onsubmit
let forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
forms.forEach(frm => frm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    // Evitar que se procese
    e.preventDefault();
    // Verificar que se cambió la acción
    console.log(frm.action);
}));
/* ********** ...hasta aquí ********** */
```

```html
<form method='POST'>
  <input class='results' type='submit' value='Resultados' />
  <input class='update' type='submit' value='Modificar' />
  <input class='delete' type='submit' value='Eliminar' />
</form>

<form method='POST'>
  <input class='results' type='submit' value='Resultados' />
  <input class='update' type='submit' value='Modificar' />
  <input class='delete' type='submit' value='Eliminar' />
</form>

<form method='POST'>
  <input class='results' type='submit' value='Resultados' />
  <input class='update' type='submit' value='Modificar' />
  <input class='delete' type='submit' value='Eliminar' />
</form>
```

Para poder hacer validaciones, dentro de cada función tienes el formulario y, desde ahí puedes usar `.querySelector()` para obtener los campos y verificar que estén correctos, ejemplo, suponiendo que tienes un campo `name="nombre"`:

```
// Para actualizar
function update(e) {
  // Obtener formulario, closest buscará el elemento especificado
  // en la estructura superior
  let form = e.target.closest('form');
  // Obtener valor del campo "nombre"
  let nombre = form.querySelector('[name="nombre"]').value;
  if(nombre == '') {
    // Si hay error, no procesar el formulario
    e.preventDefault();
    // Mostrar el error
    alert('Nombre no puede quedar vacío');
    return;
  }
  if (confirm("¿Seguro que quieres modificar esta encuesta? ")) {
     // Asignar acción
     form.action = 'survey-update.php';
  } else {
     // Respuesta negativa, se cancela el proceso de formulario
     e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Seguramente debes aplicar otro tipo de validaciones, esto es solo un ejemplo.